# Extracting one value from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, selection

I have a list of dictionaries which has product info including reviews of each product. This is called "products_dicts"

Each product has a field called "Reviews"

I want to extract the Reviews for the product with a "uniq_id" = "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d"

I have tried the following:

```
for item in products_dicts():
    if "uniq_id" == "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d"
    print(products_dicts.Reviews)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for product in products_dicts:
    if product["uniq_id"] == "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d":
        print(product["reviews"])
```

Comment: It states list object is not callable :(

Comment: yes remove the brackets from product_dicts I have made changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your dictionaries look like this is best guess:

```
for item in products_dicts:
    if item.get('uniq_id') == 'b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d':
        print(item.get('Reviews'))
```